# Include php var into Mysql Addtime

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot solve query including a simple PHP var. Testing with static value works. But replacing with variable leave same value... any idea?

```
<?php
  $var = "2" /// 2minutes;

  $resultrest = mysql_query("UPDATE times SET 
     time = adddate(time, interval '$var' MINUTE) /// with static value "2" work fine adding time
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; ") or die(mysql_error()
  );

  if($resultrest){                                      
     die('1');/// for response
  }
?>
```

The time column is TIME type

```
id    | race_id     | car_num | time       |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------+
1     | 8           | 25      | 00:09:05   |
2     | 8           | 33      | 00:09:35   |
```

Comment: basics,,, trace it, echo the variable you are trying to use

Comment: echo print fine, but this is a controller and only echo for responses (any other suggestion?)

Answer (score 0):

If the static value work fine. Maybe you should insert it like this.

```
 $resultrest = mysql_query("UPDATE times SET 
 time = adddate(time, interval ".$var." MINUTE) 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I don't know what's wrong with your first query so you have to wait for the next answer about what happened in your first query. But my above code should work for you if static value works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use var without '' and concate the query string:

```
<?php
  $var = 2 /// 2minutes;

  $resultrest = mysql_query("UPDATE times SET 
     time = adddate(time, interval ".$var." MINUTE) 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; ") or die(mysql_error()
  );

  if($resultrest){                                      
     echo('OK');
  }
?>
```